# How to merge more than one cell in one new cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Dears,

I want to merge more than one cell and put it inside a new cell. Please see the below image for the example.

Thanks for your support.

***Example:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### In-Cell Line Break

You can use the in-cell line break, keyboard shortcut `ALT`+`ENTER`, and enter the values one below other inside one cell.

So in B12 you type

1. 121
2. `ALT`+`ENTER`
3. 123
4. `ALT`+`ENTER`
5. ...

### Formula with line breaks

You can use a formula to achieve the result.
`=IF(A2=A1;C1&CHAR(10)&B2;TEXT(B2;"@"))`, where `CHAR(10)` is a line break character.
Then you select the cells with result and toggle *word wrap* on. See picture:

[image]

You can then copy and paste as values, delete the rows you dont need.

Comment: i want code or formula to do it automatically because I have a lot of values

Comment: For future, you should come up with your solutions and ask questions only when you get **stuck on those, not demand free solutions.** Please DO read more in [Stack Overflow Help - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Range ("b12").value = range ("b2").value & vbLf & range ("b3").value & vbLf etc...